# Checking for occurrence of value in postgres - NodeJS

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

Within my database my data can look one of two ways

1 -

```
hh_match_count: 5,
hh_total_fhc_0: 6,
hh_total_fhc_1: 5,
hh_total_fhc_2: 3,
hh_total_fhc_3: 2,
hh_total_fhc_4: 4
```

2 -

```
hh_match_count: 3,
hh_total_fhc_0: 6,
hh_total_fhc_1: 5,
hh_total_fhc_2: 3,
hh_total_fhc_3: null,
hh_total_fhc_4: null
```

What I want to do is calculate the number of times a value is >= 1 (will want to expand this to >= 2, >= 3 etc) from each of `hh_total_fhc_0, hh_total_fhc_1, hh_total_fhc_2, hh_total_fhc_3, hh_total_fhc_4` and then divide that by `hh_match_count`. So basically getting the % of occurrences.

What query should I be looking at executing here? Slowly getting more involved with SQL statements.

Comment: Use [least](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) to turn your values into 1 or 0; since you've got nulls, `coalesce` will also be helpful. Then add everything together and divide by `hh_match_count`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you be able to assist further please with an example ?

Comment: Why don't you try writing a few queries yourself and see if you actually have a problem? Start with adding field values together, then see about reducing positive integers to ones and so on.

Comment: Hi, @dmfay i've posted an update to my question.Is my interpretation of what is required correct ?

Answer (score 0):

`coalesce` returns the first non-null value it's passed. That turns your null values into zeroes, since you need to count them as zero for the average. Next step is to add `least` to the mix:

`SELECT least(1, coalesce(hh_total_fhc_0, 0)) FROM fixtures` gives you a 0 if the value is zero (crucially, null isn't a number so `least(1, null)` is 1!), and a 1 if it's a positive value. Apply that to each of your columns and then you can calculate the hit percentage exactly as you were thinking.

Comment: Im not sure if i have explained the question correctly or I am not understanding where you are coming from, so if `hh_total_fhc_0` == `5` we know that `1` has happened. This would mean that `SELECT least(1, coalesce(hh_total_fhc_0, 0)) FROM fixtures WHERE id = 182` for example will return `1`. But what if I wanted to check that `6` has occurred, that's more than `5`, so would that return `0` ? that query would look like `SELECT least(6, coalesce(hh_total_fhc_0, 0)) FROM fixtures`

Comment: I have updated the wording in my question, hopefully it makes more sense

Comment: So I understand what least is doing now, which helps me with checking for number 1.My problem now though is what if I want to check for 2 occurrences and then 3 and so on